# My computer keeps freezing since updating to 18.04

Tags: freeze

I was using ubuntu 17 for a while and I deceided to upgrade it via terminal , however mostly when I tried to log in it froze with a purple screen and nothing really worked as a permanent solution , so I deceided to install it again using an USB ,  but it keeps freezing at the installer and at this point even the previous OS got corrupted , does any1 know the source / fix to this problem ?

Comment: I already re formatted the stick with a different version but now it says i have 0 bytes left ( which shouldn’t be true) anyway I tried fdisk -ing my partitions since I don’t meed them anymore but I still don’t have space ?

Comment: If you have not verified the 18.04 install image, following the instructions at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0, please do so before proceeding further.